# A sort of formal way for saying "that sounds like a new work"

Tags: sentence-construction, politeness

Suppose, you submit your report to a boss and he asks you to add more chapters or sections to the report. However, you don't want to do that because you believe the new content would be too much and they qualify for being in a separate report.

Now suppose that you want to say or imply that this request sounds like a new report. How would you say that politely and professionally? I don't want to tell this very formally though. That's why I asked this question to know how you native speakers would phrase this.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off asking this over on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).  This kind of "business-speak" is not something every English speaker will know; plus it's constantly evolving.

However, to answer the question:  a common term when talking about what is and is not within the specifications of a project is "scope":

> I believe these additional sections would be **outside the scope** of this report.  It would be better to create a new report.

However, you should be clear to define whether you are talking about the "scope" of the report itself, or the "scope" of a particular project.  Additional sections may work fine within the existing specs, but the added tasks may keep you from finishing other parts of the project:

For example:

> I believe this is **outside the scope of the project**.  If I take on this additional work it may impact my ability to hit some of the other milestones.

Answer (score 0):

This question definitely has a lot of facets, many of which should be asked on other SE boards.

Skipping everything interpersonal and contractual, you still have different options depending on the details.

If you think this should be a separate project because it covers too many topics or talks about too many things, or is simply too large for its ultimate purpose, you could simply describe it as too broad of a report. You could also describe it as unwieldy to highlight the clumsiness of packing this information into one report.

If the additions are more advanced instructions or in-depth analysis, say it would be "appropriate" to divide it for those reasons.

If this changes how you get paid, object based on the "scope of work" for the project.